# Huge outline in winterbash page on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash-2016

Open a hat in the winterbash page on Firefox, e.g.

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-am-your-father

Then click the close button. When focused, it receives an outline.

The problem is that the `text-indent: -999em` hack used to hide its text does affect the outline:

[image]

Just add `overflow: hidden` to fix

[image]

Comment: I get no outline at all

Comment: @Cai It seems Chrome does not add outline to links by default.

Comment: no outline on Firefox either (49.0.2 macOS)

Comment: I have that too. it is just the active state for me.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: True, seems OS dependent. I get the outline on Linux but not on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not repro locally, but I've added the fix proposed. Can you confirm it's fixed now?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed!